# invalid conversion from int to UIBarStyle, objective-c++

Tags: iphone, xcode, build

I am trying to integrate a popular iphone module(ShareKit).

The module builds and works fine in the provided sample project.

I've added the appropriate files to my project and it won't compile.
I suspect it's due to some project settings of my project.

most of errors are

```
Invalid conversion from 'int' to 'UIBarStyle'   
Cannot convert 'UIInterfaceOrientation' to 'UIDeviceOrientation' in assignment   
Invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'UIAccessibilityTraits*'
```

I've googled and it seems no similar errors were reported related to Sharekit.

Any guess on what setting is messing up the conversion?
I'm mixxing c++ / object-c in my project.

Comment: Please provide the code that is causing the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's because c++ is more strict on type checking than pure objective-c.

just type-casted them all.